# Best practice for organizing automated testing?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I am writing an automated testing for an application and currently have around 150 test cases. Everything runs fine, but as the tests keep growing, I continuously run into the problem of figuring out how to organize the test cases.

Some tests will rely on previous tests (e.g. I can't log in until I've opened the application, I can't preform an action until I've logged in). At run time, I currently have a UI that allows the user to select which test cases to run, and it gets tricky trying to sort them once I have this list.

I feel that it would not be worth my time to have a predefined order for the test cases because not all will be run each time, and I would have to update this list each time I add a new test.

Does anyone with experience in automated testing, or testing in general, have any recommendations?

Note: I tried to add an integer flag to each test, and then order them that way, but that caused a lot of problems and any time I added a new test that occurred in the middle some tests had to be shifted (and that is a pain for 150+ test cases).

**EDIT**

I would just like to clarify another example for tests that may rely on each other, not just logging in or opening the application. For this software, the user can upload data in the application. They can then go and download a report for this data. Obviously, if the user only selects the 'download' test, there's nothing I can do. However, if the user selects 'upload' and 'download', I need a way to ensure that upload is preformed first.

Comment: Tests shouldn't rely on previous tests to run. What if you want to run "log in" tests only without running "open app" tests. Each test should have its own setup which will setup everything for the test to run on its own.

Comment: That's a really good point, I should (and will) protect against things such as log in and opening application, but I edited the question to clarify a different example in which tests may rely on each other.

Comment: Again, after your edit, tests should be independent. If you want to test upload, you test that your application uploads files to the server successfully. If you want to test download, first you upload files to your server in your test setup, then test that uploaded files in your server can be downloaded.

Comment: I understand. I guess I'm working too hard to find a way to optimize it. Would you recommend doing a test (not an actual test, but using a few lines of code) to find out if data has already been uploaded? Or should every test be strictly independent regardless of what happens before or after it. That would be a HUGE overhaul, but this is for company software and I've only done a minor portion of test cases, I want to safeguard myself for the best methods of expansion in the future.

Comment: Also, @artm , I really appreciate your help. It's definitely pushed me in the right direction when I was stuck. If you want to organize those suggestions and give an answer to the question, I'd happily accept and upvote your answer.

Comment: Tests shouldn't care what happens before or after them, otherwise your tests might fail not because your code doesn't work, but because your tests don't work. Then you'll be wasting time trying to figure out why your code fails, when it's in fact the test that fails. Look into testsetup and testclear, every test sets up whatever it needs to run and then once it's finished it clears up after itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tests shouldn't rely on previous tests to run. What if you want to run "log in" tests only without running "open app" tests. Each test should have its own setup which will setup everything for the test to run on its own. If you want to test upload, you test that your application uploads files to the server successfully. If you want to test download, first you upload files to your server in your test setup, then test that uploaded files in your server can be downloaded.

Tests shouldn't care/rely on what happens before them, otherwise your tests might fail not because your code doesn't work, but because your tests don't work. Then you'll be wasting time trying to figure out why your code fails, when it's in fact the test that fails. Look into testsetup and testclear, every test sets up whatever it needs to run and then once it's finished it clears up after itself, so every test is clear of other tests.

Comment: Definitely going to refactor this whole thing. It's a pain now, but it will definitely aid moving forward. I can refactor a lot too, ex: some tests will have a shared setup and clear, so there's plenty of re usability. Thanks again.

Comment: @McAdam331 Also look into TestFixtureSetup/TearDown and TestSetup/TearDown. One sets up the environment for every test to run in a class, other sets up the environment for individual test cases. So in your TestFixtureSetup you can create a temp folder. Each test creates a file in that temp folder and deletes the file in TearDown. And finally in your TestFixture tear down, you delete the temp folder. So you don't need to create the temp folder in each of your tests. Keep in mind when you're refactoring your tests.

Comment: One more thing that could help you organizing, during test setup of a lot of tests you may notice that you have common steps. If that happens to be the case, I recommend creating a separate project that will do these things for you, outside of your tests, your tests will just call these. For example on what artm says about testing download functionality, I would create in the separate project a method that would upload files, since that's a prerequisite of the test, and other tests will reuse it for sure.